# How to get attribute values of an XML and code as thead values for html using xslt

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xpath

I am currently using an XSLT to pull values out of an XML document and create a new HTML document. Part of my xml, XSLT codes are below. I don't know how to show the thead values of html from attribute values of xml:

Source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<Summary>
  <test name="test">
    <xml_name name="ABC">
        <version num="1.0">
            <component name="APPS">
                <componenet_ver>104</componenet_ver>
            </component>
        <component name="Ner">
            <componenet_ver>1.0</componenet_ver>
            </component>
            <component name="HUNE">
                <componenet_ver>003</componenet_ver>
            </component>
            <component name="FADA">
                <componenet_ver>107</componenet_ver>
            </component>
            <component name="VEDA">
                <componenet_ver>8.8</componenet_ver>
            </component>
        </version>
    </xml_name>
  </test>
</Summary>
```

XSLT file I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Compo. Name and Versions</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="/Summary/test/xml_name"/></th>    ### this line
        <th><xsl:value-of select="/Summary/test/xml_name/version"/></th>    ###  and this line
      </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="/Summary/test/xml_name/version/component">
                  <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="componenet_ver"/></td>
                  </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Getting o/p:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You were not specifying the attributes in your XPath expressions.
So simply use this code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Compo. Name and Versions</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="/Summary/test/xml_name/@name"/></th>
        <th><xsl:value-of select="/Summary/test/xml_name/version/@num"/></th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Summary/test/xml_name/version/component">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="componenet_ver"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output should be as expected:

[image]

Comment: @ikegami: yes, I guessed so, too. I have been unsure if I should mention it. But because this apparently the wrong decision, I now removed this.